# Detect surfaces from a binary numpy array (image)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, detection

Assume that I have a binary numpy array (0 or 1 / True or False) that come from a .jpg image (2D array, from a grayscale image). I just made some processing to get the edges of the image, based on color change.

Now, from every surface/body from this array I need to get its centers.

Here the original image:

[image: Original image]

Here the processed one:
[image: Processed image - a 2D np.array]

Now I need to get the centers of each surface generated for this lines (i.e. indexes that more or less point the center of each surface generated).

In the case you are interested, you can find the file (.npy) here:

```
https://gofile.io/d/K8U3ZK
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works. `scipy.ndimage.label` assigns a unique int. to each label or area, to validate the results I simply plot the output array

```py
from scipy.ndimage import label

labeled_array, no_feats = label(my_binary_flower)
plt.imshow(labeled_array)
```